# Color Blind a c++ program

Tags: c++, windows

I need my program to "see" different colors.

Pretty much all I need is a function which tells the color of a single pixel on my screen by using the x-coordinate and the y-coordinate. I hope there is a function like that :P

Coordinates go in.

```
string color;
TellColor(126, 1024, color);
cout << color;
```

Color comes out.
Green

I did some searching though and I found a great function called GetPixel, but as far as I can know it can only tell colors from a image file. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are multiple aspects to this question: getting a pixel value from the screen (this is platform dependent - which operating system are you on? Is the pixel in your app or somewhere on the whole screen?), and translating its r,g,b value into a human-readable word. You'll do better asking 2 separate questions if you need both answered.

Comment: What platform are you on? This will be highly platform dependent. I'm guessing that because you're talking about [GetPixel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144909(v=vs.85).aspx) you're using Windows?

Comment: Since this concerns I/O, information on the used platform would be useful.

Comment: You want the color returned in a text form?  That could be a bit verbose given the range of colors available on modern video systems.  What should be returned for green with just a tinge, (not a touch or a thimblefull), of magenta?

Comment: Actually, it could be an interesting question.  If you restrict the number of discrete colors that can be output, (say, as an example, 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'cyan', 'magenta', yellow', 'white', 'black'), and have a lookup table that contains the RGB values for each color, and given some RGB color vaue from an image, how would you decide which table entry is 'nearest' to the image value?

Comment: sir i am using windows platform

Comment: I've had another thought, (I must stop that!).  My IDE's have color palettes where the colors have names.  Perhaps these colors come from the OS, maybe there's an API to list/iterate 'known' colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope it help

The GetPixel function retrieves the red, green, blue (RGB) color value of the
    pixel at the specified coordinates.

```
COLORREF GetPixel(

    HDC hdc,    // handle of device context  
    int XPos,   // x-coordinate of pixel 
    int nYPos   // y-coordinate of pixel 
   );
```

Parameters

```
hdc
```

Identifies the device context.

```
nXPos
```

Specifies the logical x-coordinate of the pixel to be examined.

```
nYPos
```

Specifies the logical y-coordinate of the pixel to be examined.

Return Values

If the function succeeds, the return value is an RGB value. If the pixel is outside of the
    current clipping region, the return value is CLR_INVALID. 
    Remarks

The pixel must be within the boundaries of the current clipping region. 
Not all devices support GetPixel. An application should call GetDeviceCaps to determine
whether a specified device supports this function.

See Also

```
GetDeviceCaps, SetPixel
```

Comment: For the `hdc`, use `GetDC(0)`. (And call `ReleaseDC` when done)